# How to generate tags file for a C++ STL template file like future?

Tags: c++, stl, tags, ctags

I want to generate a tags file for C++ STL file. But it seems not works well.
For example, I use below command

```
 sudo ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q future
```

'future' is a file from gcc

as a result, tags file like below

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/                                                                                                     
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
```

can not find any tag like 'async', 'future' which are define in file, future, like below,

```
  template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
    future<typename result_of<_Fn(_Args...)>::type>
    async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);

  template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
    future<typename result_of<_Fn(_Args...)>::type>                                                                                                                                   
    async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);
```

Comment: Aren't ctags capabilities rather limited and isn't attempt to parse fancy variadic templates way overoptimistic?

Answer (score 1):

You specified "future" as input file name on the command line. I don't know which implementation of ctags you are using, but I guess ctags cannot know the language used in future. So ctags cannot choose a parser suitable for "future". If you specify a language for "future" explicitly with --language-force=C++, ctags may work well. Following lines shows Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) tags two "async".

```
[jet@localhost]/tmp% cat future
template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
future<typename result_of<_Fn(_Args...)>::type>
async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);

template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
future<typename result_of<_Fn(_Args...)>::type>                                                                                                                                   
async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);

[jet@localhost]/tmp% ctags --version
Universal Ctags 0.0.0(d30a62d), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jun 26 2017, 00:15:01
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +multibyte, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +sandbox, +yaml, +aspell

[jet@localhost]/tmp% ctags --kinds-C++=+p --fields=+iaS --extras=+q --language-force=C++ -o - future
async   future  /^async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);$/;" p   typeref:typename:future<typename result_of<_Fn (_Args...)>::type>   file:   signature:(_Fn && __fn,_Args &&...__args)
async   future  /^async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args);$/;"    p   typeref:typename:future<typename result_of<_Fn (_Args...)>::type>   file:   signature:(launch __policy,_Fn && __fn,_Args &&...__args)
```